# How to Escape "%" in parameters.yml symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

I would like escape a character `%` in file : parameters.yml, because my password begin by `%`

```
database_driver3: pdo_sqlsrv
database_host3: 192.168.10.10
database_port3: 1455
database_name3: MyDB
database_user3: sa
database_password3: %ABC$Admin_2012%
```

What I really should be doing ?

Comment: double `%%` will escape one `%`

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to simply add quotes to the values you want to escape

```
database_password3: "%ABC$Admin_2012%"
```

OR by using double % credit - skowron-line

```
database_password3: %%ABC$Admin_2012%%
```

Comment: Quoting doesn't seem to work. In fact, starting from Symfony 3.1 you should quote all scalars starting with % and Symfony still processes them as parameters https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-yaml-deprecations#deprecated-starting-scalars-with-characters 

Using double % does work though

Comment: Using double % alone does not work for me within Symfony 4.2. Only using quotes _and_ using double % seems to work.

Comment: using quotes and using double % doesn't work for me  SF 5.x

Comment: @medunes single quotes with double % works fine for me in SF 5.3