# How to have website link in twig using text in yaml file

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml, href

I want to have hyperlinks where the text is surrounded by the percentage symbol `%website%` `%exmple@fraudline.co.za%` `%fraud@example.co.za%`

This is my yaml file:

```
fraud_details:
    fraud_message: |
                If you suspect atm fraud, you can report it safely, easily and
                anonymously to the %website% toll-free insurance fraudline: 0860 000 000,
                email %example@fraudline.co.za% or SMS 31111.
                Alternatively, please send an email to %fraud@example.co.za%.
```

And this is how I'd use the yaml text in twig template:

```
<div>{{ 'fraud_details.fraud_message'|trans({},'messages')|nl2br }}</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Escape "%" in parameters.yml symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274230/how-to-escape-in-parameters-yml-symfony2)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use html tags and add the `raw` filter as follows:

```
fraud_details:
    fraud_message: |
                Bla bla bla
                bla <a href="%website1%">%website1%</a>,
                bla <a href="%website2%">%website2%</a>,
                bla bla <a href="mailto:%mail%">%mail%</a>.
```

Then you can directly use it in the twig template either by using a string, a path, a twig variable or whatever you want (don't forget the `raw` filter):

```
<div>{{ 'fraud_details.fraud_message'|trans({'%website1%': "https://www.example.com", '%website2%': path('some_route'), '%mail%': somevar},'messages')|raw|nl2br }}</div>
```